# Excel VBA: Horizontal axis categories showing numbers but source data has text labels

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am dynamically assigning data to a chart. The data itself is also dynamically generated. My problem is that even though my source data contains string labels (e.g. Dept1, Dept2), the chart displays only numbers (1, 2) on the horizontal axis. I have performed a manual action of 'select data' on the chart and ensure that the Horizontal Category Labels contains reference to the labels. The image below should explain it better:
[image: Sample Image]

I am pasting my VBA code a bit later. Here's the steps I'm performing in the sheet:

1. User is provided a 'form' to select what data to see - Updating the values in certain cells dynamically fetches data from another sheet and pastes it in my main sheet. The data is always two columns - one containing labels and the other their associated values.
2. When data in the main sheet is updated, I find the range size and pass it to the chart as its source data, including the labels.
3. Depending on the user selections, the chart type varies between clustered column and line.

Here is sample data in CSV format. Note that I am not passing headers.
*Sample 1:*

```
Dept1,2105  
Dept2,1569  
Dept3,1891  
Dept4,265
```

*Sample 2:*

```
42614,693.5  
42644,610.5  
42675,851.5  
42705,852
```

In sample two, the labels are formatted as Mmm-yy dates (Sep-16 to Dec-16).

Here's the VBA code:

```
Sub drawGraph(viewType As String)

'This sub will be called by the sub responsible for prepping data
'Each view format needs a separate type of visualisation to be shown
'this sub will figure out which graph to show and show it

Dim data As Range
Dim firstRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
Dim formats As Worksheet
Dim formatRow As Long
Dim formatCol As Long

On Error GoTo errExit

'Hide all graph columns
Set mainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main Sheet")
mainSheet.Select
mainSheet.Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(1, 51)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

'View Type 1 has no graph, escape with if condition
If Not viewType = "View Type 1" Then
    'Pre-prepared view types (graph, text, etc.) are placed in certain hidden columns, each spanning 9 columns. 
    'We need to find the starting column of the view type that we need.
    Set formats = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formats Base")
    formats.Select
    formats.Columns("A:A").Select
    formatRow = Selection.Find(What:=viewType, _
                            After:=Range("A1"), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    formatCol = formats.Cells(formatRow, 4)
    mainSheet.Activate
    'unhide 9 columns
    'all graphs are designed to fit within 9 columns
    'Might not be the most efficient way to do this but it's the only one I know
    Union(Columns(formatCol), Columns(formatCol + 1), Columns(formatCol + 2), _
    Columns(formatCol + 3), Columns(formatCol + 4), Columns(formatCol + 5), _
    Columns(formatCol + 6), Columns(formatCol + 7), Columns(formatCol + 8), Columns(formatCol + 9)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    'Need to assign data to chart
    'View Type 2 does not have a graph, escape with if condition
    If Not viewType = "View Type 2" Then
        mainSheet.Cells(6, 22).Value = ""
        Set cht = mainSheet.ChartObjects("dataGraph")
        Select Case viewType
            Case "View Type 3"
                cht.chart.chartType = xlColumnClustered
            Case "View Type 4 - Months"
                cht.chart.chartType = xlLine
            Case "View Type 5"
                cht.chart.chartType = xlColumnClustered
        End Select
        firstRow = 4
        lastRow = mainSheet.Range("H1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        Set data = mainSheet.Range(Cells(firstRow, 8), Cells(lastRow, 9))
        cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=data

    ElseIf viewType = "View Type 2" Then
        mainSheet.Cells(6, 22).Value = "=$I$3/$V$4"
    End If
End If


errExit:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```